# Checkbox in js - validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a fragment of my code. Can I add an ID to this  portion? Now I have 2 groups of check boxes (topic, interests). When I check the box in the group and I do not check the box in the second group, an error message appears.

My idea: add ID to this "input [type = checkbox]: selected" and add all of it to IF. Is it possible to do it ?

Under the text is my idea what it should look like:

```
#I know it doesn't work. 
if(($('input[type=checkbox][id=subject]:checked').length == 0) && $('input[type=checkbox][id=interests]:checked').length == 0))
```

```
<script>
function validate_form()
{
    valid = true;
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
{
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Please tick one box for interests and topics";
    valid = false;
}

    return valid;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you also share the html?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to others if you could provide the error code. As you mentioned you have one.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following steps:

- add attribute class for group's checkboxes
- add div for every block of interests and set id depending on the group id
- on validate, get interests div block by checked group id

Like this:

```
$('.group:checked').each(function() {
    const groupInterestsId = `#${this.id}Interests`
    if ($(`${groupInterestsId} input[type="checkbox"]:checked`).length === 0) {
    alert('Please select interests for selected group')
    return false;
  }
})
```

See full example on my sandbox: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/bosqhruf/34/#&togetherjs=60jflqRT4b